# How do I limit the amount of times my player can respawn in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to limit the amount of times my player can respawn to 3 or 5 respawns before a game over screen displays. How do I do this? And how exactly do I code in/add the screen in at the end? Should I just call on the screen (from another scene)? Im new to Unity so im sorry if this makes no sense. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please one question at a time, and please share your code along with a specific problem or error you are facing when running that code. You can learn about how to ask questions in [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic of how you would solve the problem. Have a counter, that is defaulted to a value such as 5. Every time the player respawns, you reduce from the counter, so you know how many times they have died. Then you have a check so if they haven't died 5 times yet, respawn, but if they have died 5 times, it's game over. For the game over menu, don't transition to a new scene. Have a disabled game object in the same scene, and activate it when it's game over.

```
public int respawns = 5;  // create a variable for how many times the player can respawn before displaying the gameover screen
public GameObject gameOverMenu; // this is the menu you want to activate in unity when they can no longer respawn

private void Start ()
{
    gameOverMenu.SetActive (false); // make sure that the game over menu is off by default

}

private void Update()
{
    if (YOUR PLAYER DIES)
    {
        if (respawns > 0) // if they haven't respawned 5 times yet
        {
            //respawn the player
            respawns--; // remove 1 from the amount of time they can respawn
        }
        else 
        {
            gameOverMenu.SetActive (true); // enable the game over menu
        }
    }
 }
```

The logic is there and you have to insert it into your script. If you want a more direct answer, please post your current script.

Comment: If this answered your question then mark it as correct so other people with a similar problem know :)